# Asymptote and Exsheets

Tags: asymptote, exsheets

How can I use `asymptote` language inside an `exsheets` question?

For example, the code below will compile perfectly fine. But if the `asypicture` environment is moved inside the `exsheets` question environment, then errors happen.

(The same behavior is used if `asy` environment from `asymptote` package is used.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

    \begin{question}
        How can I use asymptote inside a question?
    \end{question}

    \begin{asypicture}{}
        import graph3;
        import palette;

        size3(400,400,200,IgnoreAspect);
        currentprojection=orthographic(1,-3,50);

        real f(pair r) {return r.x^3-3*r.x*r.y^2;}

        real Arg(triple v) {return degrees(cos(v.z),warn=false);}

        surface s=surface(f,(-4,-4),(4,4),20,Spline);

        s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()+opacity(0.75) ));
        draw(s,render(compression=Low,merge=true),meshpen=black);

        real xmin = -5;
        real xmax = +5;
        real ymin = -5;
        real ymax = +5;
        pen axisPen = red + 0.75;
        draw(Label("$x$",1),(xmin,0,0)--(xmax,0,0),axisPen,Arrow3);
        draw(Label("$y$",1),(0,ymin,0)--(0,ymax,0),axisPen,Arrow3);

        pen p=fontsize(12pt);
        pair P = (2.5,-2);
        dot("$P$",(P.x,P.y,f(P)),N,p);

        xaxis3("$x$",Bounds,InTicks);
        yaxis3("$y$",Bounds,InTicks(beginlabel=false));
        zaxis3("$f$",Bounds,InTicks);
    \end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't. In fact, you can't even use the `verbatim` environment inside an exsheets `question` environment. [Which suggests that this "environment" is really a command in disguise.]

Long answer: You can do it if you are prepared to subvert the package slightly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

    \begin{asypicture}{}
        import graph3;
        import palette;

        size3(400,400,200,IgnoreAspect);
        currentprojection=orthographic(1,-3,50);

        real f(pair r) {return r.x^3-3*r.x*r.y^2;}

        real Arg(triple v) {return degrees(cos(v.z),warn=false);}

        surface s=surface(f,(-4,-4),(4,4),20,Spline);

        s.colors(palette(s.map(zpart),Rainbow()+opacity(0.75) ));
        draw(s,render(compression=Low,merge=true),meshpen=black);

        real xmin = -5;
        real xmax = +5;
        real ymin = -5;
        real ymax = +5;
        pen axisPen = red + 0.75;
        draw(Label("$x$",1),(xmin,0,0)--(xmax,0,0),axisPen,Arrow3);
        draw(Label("$y$",1),(0,ymin,0)--(0,ymax,0),axisPen,Arrow3);

        pen p=fontsize(12pt);
        pair P = (2.5,-2);
        dot("$P$",(P.x,P.y,f(P)),N,p);

        xaxis3("$x$",Bounds,InTicks);
        yaxis3("$y$",Bounds,InTicks(beginlabel=false));
        zaxis3("$f$",Bounds,InTicks);
        shipout("my_picture");
    \end{asypicture}

    \begin{question}
        How can I use asymptote inside a question?

        \includegraphics{my_picture}
    \end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By including the `shipout` command with a name other than the default, you make Asymptote produce an image with a name that the `asypicture` environment does not expect. Consequently, the `asypicture` environment doesn't get a graphic to include, but you can include the real graphics at a later time of your choosing. The same trick should work for the `asy` environment in the `asymptote` package (I think).

Downsides:

1. If you do this, the Asymptote picture will be recompiled every time you run latex (with shell-escape enabled), even if it has not changed.
2. There may be a bit of extra space at the `asypicture` environment. (I'm actually not sure how this works, although I'm sure there are people on this site who could figure it out fairly easily.)

As an alternative, you might consider putting your Asymptote code in an `asy` file, compiling it with Asymptote, and then including only the image (but not the asymptote code) in your `tex` file. At least in your MWE, it doesn't look like you are using any features that really require the Asymptote code to be specified within the `tex` file.

Comment: Why can't `asypicture` be used as argument of a macro? Does it do catcode changes?

Comment: @clemens: Yes. The `asypicture` environment uses `verbatim`-like setup to write its contents to a file, which is processed with the Asymptote program to produce an image.